# Newest Agile Design Methods for code construction

Tags: agile, design-principles

Hallo everybody

Recently I've been reading the book:

"Agile software development, Principles, Patterns and Practices" by Bob Martin

The following (S.O.L.I.D) agile-design-principles are listed within the book:

- Single Responsibility Principle
- Open Closed Principle Principle
- Liskov Substitution Principle
- Interface Segregation Principle
- Dependency Inversion Principle

Because of the fact that this book quite old(2003), I have a question:

1. Are there any other newly developed principles besides the SOLID methods?? If yes, is there any book/site covering these new emerging principles with practical code examples that you could recommend to me??

Of course I can google for some of these.

However, in stackoverflow read and write many profis, so I would like to hear their opinion too :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to look at books such as [Code Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670) and [Pragmatic Programmer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020161622X) as they also talk about some excellent development principles.

Answer (score 4):

I like the Domain Driven Design approach from Eric Evans:

- http://domaindrivendesign.org/
- http://domaindrivendesign.org/books#DDD

As the SOLID approach you describe, DDD is mostly sound and clean Object Orientation guidelines. DDD focus especially on creating a design which match as much as possible with the business to be implemented in the system, rather than having it guided by the technology and/or the frameworks you use. This lead to great testable design, easy to refactor.

In support to DDD, I like the Hexagonal Architecture of Alistair Cockburn. It gives you great ideas about general design of Object Oriented systems:

- http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture

A more advanced and innovative approach I am currently exploring is the theory of centers, but this is not yet really documented. A presentation about it:

- http://www.dreamsongs.com/Files/NatureOfOrder.pdf

Answer (score 2):

UncleBob's book is a SOLID start ;) I'd add his Clean Code to your reading list too. For actual code construction it is a great tome.

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: Clean Code is the Best-Of version of Bob Martin's writings.  Highly recommended if you want to get just one book that covers a lot.

Comment: Clean Code has some nice ideas, but I prefer the other books written by Uncle Bob and other Object Mentors. Clean Code does not cover SOLID solidly (though it is mentioned in the index).

Answer (score 0):

You can find further design principles at http://www.objectmentor.com, the author's / Object Mentor's homepage.  They were written around the same time as SOLID, you can find most of them at http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/publishedArticles.html.

Answer (score 0):

This list is not for design principles only, but also an explanation of OOP, Agile architecture, design and practices, it is based on patterns of mistakes and a regular pain from my real projects, including both books and online articles:

[Software Developer / Architect Recommended Reading](http://www.agiledesignllc.com/SoftwareDeveloperRecommendedReading)